# removeEventListener not removing listener in firebase

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to remove addValueEventListener listener from a firebase ref when value of particular field is true.

```
ValueEventListener valueListener=null;

private void removeListener(Firebase fb){
    if(valueListener!=null){
        **fb.removeEventListener(valueListener);**
    }
}

String key="https://boiling-heat-3083.firebaseio.com/baseNodeAttempt/" + userId+"/"+nodeType+"/"+nodeId+"/data";
final Firebase fb = new Firebase(key);
valueListener=fb.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snap) {
        final HashMap<String, Object> data=(HashMap<String, Object>) snap.getValue();
        if( data.get("attemptFinish_"+nodeId)!=null){
            boolean title = (boolean) snap.child("attemptFinish_"+nodeId).getValue();
            if(title){
                removeListener(fb);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

But addValueEventListener is not getting removed and it's called for that firebase ref . So please suggest me how to remove listener from any firebase ref if required.

Comment: Your `valueListener` is always `null`

Comment: You can remove the listener from within the callback with `if (title) { fb.removeEventListener(this); }`. Unrelated: most readers of this code will assume that `title` is a String. You might want to use a variable name that is a bit more intuitive to interpret as a boolean, e.g. `isFinished`.

Comment: valueListener has a reference when listener is added @talex

Answer (score 18):

You can remove the listener from within the callback with:

```
ref.removeEventListener(this);
```

So a complete fragment:

```
String key="https://boiling-heat-3083.firebaseio.com/baseNodeAttempt/" + userId+"/"+nodeType+"/"+nodeId+"/data";
final Firebase ref = new Firebase(key);
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snap) {
        if (snap.hasChild("attemptFinish_"+nodeId) {
            boolean isFinished = (boolean) snap.child("attemptFinish_"+nodeId).getValue();
            if(isFinished){
                ref.removeEventListener(this);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

I removed the `HashMap`, instead using the methods of the `DataSnapshot` to accomplish the same. I also renamed a few variables to be clearer/more idiomatic.

Comment: i have tried but listener is not getting removed using  above code @ Frank van Puffelen

Comment: Did you run in a debugger? If so, is `isFinished ever `true`?

Comment: Yes its true and logger inside if statement  above ref.removeEventListener(this)  gets executed

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, what if i call ref.removeEventListener(this); at the end of onDataChange just before the }... is that fine? I tried it and it works on my project. Is there some reason you use isFinished?

Comment: Hi, thanks. Your solution works for me. After using LeakCanary, it detected the memory leak. And by removing the listener (in ValueEventListener() ) after its done fetching the data, the memory leak stop. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you add and remove the listener to the same node on your DatabaseReference. For example:

```
//when declared like this, mDatabaseReference will point to the parent node by default
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//listener added to child node "path_2"
mDatabaseReference.child(path_1).child(path_2).addChildEventListener(myListener); 
}
```

Your listener is this case is pointing to path_2.
If you try to remove your listener using this code

```
//mDatabaseReference pointing to parent node (default behaviour)
mDatabaseReference.removeEventListener(myListener);
```

it won't work because you are trying to remove the listener from the wrong node. The correct way would be

```
mDatabaseReference.child(path_1).child(path_2).removeEventListener(myListener);
```

Comment: not working for me although
But i also found this error

Answer (score 3):

I hope this will help you... just yo can use this method, it's work for me...

```
private DatabaseReference dbRef;
```

Write from onCreate()

```
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    dbRef= database.getReference("YOUR_PATH").child("KEY_NAME");
    InitListener();
    dbRef.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener); // ADDIND_LISTENER
```

Write from onDestroy()

```
if (dbRef!=null){
        dbRef.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
        valueEventListener=null;
        dbRef=null;

    }
```

Listener

```
 private void InitListener(String templeId) {
    valueEventListener=new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
```

}

Answer (score 2):

```
private DatabaseReference dbRef;
ValueEventListener mSendEventListner;

dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(phone);

ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() 
{
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                {              
                   //
                } 
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                //
            }
};
dbRef.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
mSendEventListner = valueEventListener;


//REMOVE VALUE EVENTLISTNER...
@Override
protected void onDestroy() 
{
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mSendEventListner != null) {
        dbRef.removeEventListener(mSendEventListner);
    }
}
```