# ValueEventListener executes code endlessly

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My code checks whether the value in the database equals the one that scanned the barcode everything works but Toast or SetValue happens endlessly until the camera on the Qrcode another activity from ValueEventListener run I can't so I don't know how to execute this code just once.

Here is my code where this process happens

```
 // Called when a QR is decoded
// "text" : the text encoded in QR
  // "points" : points where QR control points are placed
  @Override
  public void onQRCodeRead(String text, PointF[] points) {
   pointsOverlayView.setPoints(points);

    DatabaseReference rootRef =          FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
  DatabaseReference coinsUidRef =   rootRef.child("coinsUid").child(text);


  ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener()    {
     @SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Log.v(text,""+dataSnapshot);
    if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
      Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
              "Ошибка считвания! Считайте снова", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      toast.show();


    } else {
      long qrCoinsAmount = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);
      DatabaseReference coinsAmountRef = rootRef.child("users").child(getUid()).child("coinsAmount");
      ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {


        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          long coinsAmount = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);
          coinsAmountRef.getRef().setValue(coinsAmount + qrCoinsAmount);
           coinsUidRef.removeValue();



        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
      };
      coinsAmountRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);


    }


  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

  }

};
coinsUidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);

}
```

My Log

```
   V   /http://erwe: DataSnapshot { key = erwe, value = null }
   V/http://erwe: DataSnapshot { key = erwe, value = null }
   I/Toast: Show toast from OpPackageName:com.example.ecohelp, PackageName:com.example.ecohelp
 V/http://erwe: DataSnapshot { key = erwe, value = null }
 V/http://erwe: DataSnapshot { key = erwe, value = null }
  I/Toast: Show toast from OpPackageName:com.example.ecohelp,     PackageName:com.example.ecohelp
 V/http://erwe: DataSnapshot { key = erwe, value = null }
V/http://erwe: DataSnapshot { key = erwe, value = null }
 I/Toast: Show toast from OpPackageName:com.example.ecohelp,   PackageName:com.example.ecohelp
  I/Toast: Show toast from OpPackageName:com.example.ecohelp,      PackageName:com.example.ecohelpV/http://erwe: DataSnapshot { key = erwe, value = null }
         V/http://erwe: DataSnapshot { key = erwe, value = null }
     I/Toast: Show toast from OpPackageName:com.example.ecohelp,   PackageName:com.example.ecohelp
    V/http://erwe: DataSnapshot { key = erwe, value = null }
       V/http://erwe: DataSnapshot { key = erwe, value = null }
      I/Toast: Show toast from OpPackageName:com.example.ecohelp,    PackageName:com.example.ecohelp
       V/http://erwe: DataSnapshot { key = erwe, value = null }
          V/http://erwe: DataSnapshot { key = erwe, value = null }
        I/Toast: Show toast from OpPackageName:com.example.ecohelp, PackageName:com.example.ecohelp
     I/Toast: Show toast from OpPackageName:com.example.ecohelp,      PackageName:com.example.ecohelp
```

P.S
I just delete this value from the database and now the values in the database now change only once (as I need to) but Toast still appears endlessly

Comment: The reason seems to be `onQRCodeRead` is getting called multiple times. Put a Log ..

Comment: @ADM I added, now think that most likely you are right but unfortunately the scanner is not mine and I don't know how to edit the code it scanner all worked as it should is there any way to make that all worked without touching the scanner

Comment: Adding a listener inside an event, means that it probably is multiple times added. As listeners are hidden actors behind the scene, that is asking for a resource leak or multiple actions.

Comment: it is called multiple times because in else you are creating datachange listner and then after that you are pushing data to firbase so data is changed and in response it triggers the dataChange call back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with the  removal of Value Listener inside onDataChange

```
ref.removeEventListener(this);
```

So remove Event Listener from both references in DataChange call back. Have a look at this answer

[removeEventListener not removing listener in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30978183/removeeventlistener-not-removing-listener-in-firebase)

Comment: I just delete this value from the database and now the values in the database now change only once (as I need to) but Toast still appears endlessly

Comment: below first onDataChange,  add                              coinsAmountRef.removeEventListener(this);

and below second onDataChange , add

coinsUidRef.removeEventListener(this);